# Buttons placement convention in Android

Tags: buttons, android

Is there any convention of placing positive buttons on the right and negative on the left in Android. I know for dialog boxes this is preferred

[image]

as opposed to this because its more intuitive

[image]

But does this rule apply for all buttons which are non alert buttons?  - for instance lets say i have

> GO

and

> No Thanks

in my app , do I have to put No Thanks on the left and Go on the right ?

*Images courtesy : http://uxmovement.com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Android Design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html) mention the following:

> Action buttons are typically Cancel and/or OK, with OK indicating the
>   preferred or most likely action. However, if the options consist of
>   specific actions such as Close or Wait rather than a confirmation or
>   cancellation of the action described in the content, then all the
>   buttons should be active verbs. Order actions following these rules:
>
> - The dismissive action of a dialog is always on the left. Dismissive actions return to the user to the previous state.
> - The affirmative actions are on the right. Affirmative actions continue progress toward the user goal that triggered the dialog.

[image: Samples of Android dialog box]

**By the way, following platform conventions would be more important than changing individual dialog boxes.** As [Jakob Nielsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Nielsen_(usability_consultant)) mentioned in his [article - Alertbox, May 27, 2008](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ok-cancel.html):

> Should the OK button come before or after the Cancel button? Following
>   platform conventions is more important than suboptimizing an
>   individual dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

The convention is the opposite of what you're describing.

Left: Yes
Right: No

Yes No

Okay Cancel

Submit Cancel

Order it "Go" and "No Thanks"

Good luck!

Comment: OK Cancel are (unfortunately) differently placed on Mac and Windows and this means it's hard for Android developers to get it right. See http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ok-cancel.html

Comment: Ah, I see you're right, Ben. I was only familiar with the Apple convention. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You're welcome :-) - and welcome to our Q&A site. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! This website is just what I wanted a few days ago- a place to discuss UX design. I was thinking of hosting a voice chat room like Ventrilo for UX professionals, but this works too. :)

Comment: Thanks Tyler - Looks like Android users are used to the reverse from the guidelines guide :)