# Best principle to place button in alert dialog

Tags: buttons, dialog

For all alert dialogs with one or more buttons, which would be the best practice to place the buttons? Align left? Align right? Align Center? Please describe your reason for your choice! :) Tks!!

Comment: This is a question that has been asked before. Also, you're not even mentioning the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer may be a little biased, since most of the user of our web app are Windows users and it would be easiest for them if we maintain consistency with the OS. Any way, in *our* case the best choice was to:

- Align any single button to the right (mostly an OK or Cancel button).
- If there are two buttons, usually OK and Cancel, both gets aligned to the right in *that order*.
- Three or more buttons: if there is an OK, or Cancel button (or both) they get aligned to the right, and any other button (a Clear button, a Details button, or any other secondary tool) gets aligned to the left.
- ¿Seven buttons?: there is a tool bar that usually has 7 buttons, and it is used a lot in many forms: in that case the best solution for us was to spread all buttons in the available (and fixed) horizontal space.

You can see a short video of our web app here (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo7So9IiWrg) with the second and fourth points from above. Play attention to the seven buttons tool bar: there is a gap that separates the OK and Cancel buttons (labeled `Aceptar` and `Cancelar`) from the rest of them.

Personally I find the "centered" buttons a little out of place (I use Ubuntu at home and I see that here and there). I don't remember to have seen left aligned buttons in any program or web page unless the *main* buttons are aligned to the right.

Here are a couple of questions about the subject of "The order of buttons" in UX [Buttons placement convention in Android](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/buttons-placement-convention-in-android) and in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704951/order-of-ok-apply-cancel-buttons you may want to check.